# Can i call my database data from script tag?

Tags: php, html

I need to call out the other data from my database, but my var for id is in javascript is there any way for me to do this? or should i try using other method?

My php

```
<?php
$connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password
mysql_select_db('ts_php');
$query = "SELECT * FROM job_posted"; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
$result = mysql_query($query);
echo "<table class='table'>
        <thead>
                  <th>JOB</th>
                  <th>STATUS</th>
                  <th>APPLICATIONS</th>
                  <th>EDIT</th>
                  <th>DELETE</th>
        </thead>


    "; // start a table tag in the HTML

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
    echo "<tr>
            <th>" . $row['job_title'] . "</th>
                <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
                <td>" . $row['applications'] . "</td>
                <td><a class='openModal' data-id='".$row['post_ID']."' >edit</a></td>
                <td><a href='#'>delete</a></td>                  
            </tr>";
    }

echo "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    ?>
```

And my script

```
<script>
    $(".openModal").click(function(){
    var job_posted_id = $(this).data('id');
    $(".modal-body").html("This is your post id " + job_posted_id + "<br> This is where i want all my data");
        $(".modal").modal("show");
});
</script>
```

Comment: Have a look at [jQuery's `.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load/). You can use it to make an AJAX call to your `.php` script and insert the HTML response into the selected element

Comment: FYI, the `mysql_*` functions have been removed from the latest versions of PHP. You should be using PDO or MySQLi

Comment: [Modal](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/modal/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ajax:

```
$(".openModal").click(function(){
    var job_posted_id = $(this).data('id');
    $.get('your_function.php', {'job_posted_id':job_posted_id}, function(data) {
        $(".modal-body").html(data);
        $(".modal").modal("show");
    }, 'json');
});
```

Your php:

```
if (isset($_GET['job_posted_id']) {

    $connection = mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', ''); //The Blank string is the password
    mysql_select_db('ts_php');
    $query = "SELECT * FROM job_posted WHERE `job_posted_id` = ". $_GET['job_posted_id']; //You don't need a ; like you do in SQL
    $result = mysql_query($query);
    $str = "<table class='table'>
            <thead>
                      <th>JOB</th>
                      <th>STATUS</th>
                      <th>APPLICATIONS</th>
                      <th>EDIT</th>
                      <th>DELETE</th>
            </thead>


        "; // start a table tag in the HTML
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){   //Creates a loop to loop through results
        $str .= "<tr>
                <th>" . $row['job_title'] . "</th>
                    <td>" . $row['status'] . "</td>
                    <td>" . $row['applications'] . "</td>
                    <td><a class='openModal' data-id='".$row['post_ID']."' >edit</a></td>
                    <td><a href='#'>delete</a></td>                  
                </tr>";
        }

    $str .= "</table>"; //Close the table in HTML

    echo $str;
}
```